# Please allow me to ask questions again, after a year of being blocked

Tags: support, moderation, post-ban

I added a bounty to a question, lost 50 reputation points and found out I was no longer able to add comments under the question I placed a bounty on. Because of that I was not able to reply in comments when another user asked for more details. (Losing the ability to leave comments after placing a bounty is a design flaw after all this time.)

I think that if a user wastes 50 points to make a bounty then they should at least be able to still leave comments on their own bountied questions. I'm not crazy, this is a reasonable request.

But instead of being helped I am victim of a tremendous abuse of moderator power.

In claiming my human right to leave a comment and seeking help from a moderator, I was instead barred by a moderator from being able to ask any questions at all.

Was the moderator right to do so? I think not.

I don't pretend to know whys and reasons behind actions and abuses of moderators, I am only telling you what happened and why I can't ask questions currently.

I come here with the hope to remove the restriction in which I cannot ask a question. One year has passed, and I need to ask a question, simple as that. I didn't do anything wrong in the past to deserve this kind of restriction.

One year has happened since that discussion, but I always feel the need to ask new questions and I can't because I am restricted.

I hope a moderator can finally realised the injustice served to me.

I'm not a troll, and checking my profile you can see that I'm a user who contributes in questions and answers. I fix my questions and of other people.

But Super User too different from Stack Overflow. Super User is very hard for me to gain points because of my lack of knowledge so I do not have the same activity as I have on Stack Overflow, please understand that.

I'm asking for the possibility to ask a question, as I was able to previously.

I have learned from my errors (if any, because it was an injustice), but years have passed. Forget the past and remove me that restriction from my account.

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts, so if I understand you correctly, at least part of this shouldn't have happened. What was the post in question?

Comment: No, no in a post which has a bounty activated, of course that gave me a big surprise where I found frustrated and angry. I'll search the post

Comment: I can't find the bounty post, sorry. Maybe moderators also deleted that question too in the past. Or maybe not I'm not sure. Thanks for comment!

Comment: I fount this: http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment  anyways please note that I don't pretend to discuss this. I only pretend to remove my restriction to let me ask questions in superuser.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: In addition to my answer, I'd like to say, if there's anything to do with superuser moderation, meta.superuser is the place for overall policy related answers. The ask a superuser moderator chatroom is the place for  asking this sort of thing on chat.

Comment: Leaving a comment is not a human ("humanitary") right.

Comment: Just to note, since the question and the answers reference MSE, that I requested the question be moved here rather than be closed. There's nothing really to be done on MSE, and the question he was talking about was on SU as well. I've posted what should be a definitive answer to his issues, and it might be a good reference to what's going on, especially with some of the language used in reference to the moderation here.

Comment: *"Because of that I was not able to reply in comments when another user asked for more details."* The proper way to respond to a comment is not by leaving another comment, but rather by editing the commented-on post such that the comment has served its purpose of *requesting clarification or suggesting improvements.*

Comment: @ElektroStudios - So I provided several votes on your existing questions.  I must provide some honest feedback, I saw at least 3 questions, I would normally downvote due to what appeared to be a  lack of research you performed before asking the question.  If those votes happened to be enough, just be sure, any questions you ask are well researched, clear, high quality, and more importantly on topic.

Comment: @Ramhound Thankyou to upvoted those questions that you've considered useful. I know that in the past I wroted "bad" questions, with poor formatting and maybe with lack of research, but I've improved, I promise it. When an user keeps visiting one of the StackExchange communities it helps to learn about how to do things right, but a new user of course probably will write poor answers because does not have sufficient experience/learning in how to do it better, but as I said I've improved because I learned seeying how others publishes questions/answers, and I try to do my best. thanks for comment

Comment: @Ramhound seems that now I get unbaned!. thanks for those upvotes that you did with your criteria, sure it helped in some way. See my new question just to see what I mean: http://superuser.com/questions/986118/disable-contextmenu-item-on-desktop-background-of-windows I think I do things better now. just I wanted to comment it.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - Action speaks louder then words.  You should have submitted only quality content from the start.  You were given feedback throughout 2014, I should know, I recall your bad content which isn't a good thing.  I won't vote on your new question, I see issues, grammatical and clarity issues that should be resolved.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm a moderator at superuser, and I'd second that this happened due to the cold hard logic of an automated system, and the moderators didn't really have anything to do with this. MSU would have been the right place to ask this since *I found this by accident* (Question has since been moved to SU) and you wouldn't have gotten a response from the folks who'd be best suited to answer you. We're fine with you asking something like this on MSU, since we'd get notified and we'd be able to answer you more quickly.

Lets start with the question ban. While its automatic, and the exact rules for getting unbanned are not known to us, we can apply some basic numbers and common sense to it. *This ban was not put in place, nor can it be removed by moderators*

You have 13 closed questions of 40 questions in total, including one where a question was closed and you asked the exact same question again (This is not productive. Improve closed questions, and it goes back in the reopen queue. Do a good enough job, and they do get reopened).

Ok, slightly over a quarter of your questions. That's pretty bad but I've seen worse. A bunch of the existing questions are zero score, which might have contributed to it. Many of these were auto-deleted due to lack of answers (not out fault, its how the system works).

Here's what we *can* do however - some of your questions are roombaed. I'll review out those that were deleted and not user closed (so there's nothing wrong with them except a *lack of love*),and I'll take a look at them, and try to reopen those that meet quality standards.

However, I won't do this all at once (no point flooding the front page, and its a fair but of work) and I *cannot* promise this will lift the ban, or that the questions will not get reclosed in time if they are dead again.

On your part, you may want to edit those that you think can be improved. I believe you can always view your own deleted questions. Let me know if you need a link to these. Focus on ones with *no* closevotes and are deleted, or can be logically salvaged, not the ones that got hit by 5 off topic closevotes and such.

If any are marginal, we'll need to talk about fixing them and how, and letting me know if the ban is lifted would be awesome.

EDIT: And since I had a bit of time, here's the deleted questions on your list and some comments about them. Unfortunately, many of these are unfixable or not worth fixing. I've also undeleted a few, though I'd recomment going through them and making them better. The comments are my own opinions and aim to both prevent future issues and to help triage these. They may or may not be correct!

**Deleted questions**

https://superuser.com/questions/854532/stackexchange-design-issue clearly off topic

https://superuser.com/questions/854526/stackexchange-design-issue Also off topic

https://superuser.com/questions/830247/what-means-preload-windows-in-a-laptop-specifications not really answerable

https://superuser.com/questions/797037/what-means-the-terms-sz-cp-and-bp-on-truetype-fonts closed by 5 users, not really answerable

https://superuser.com/questions/735427/where-is-the-corresponding-registry-key-for-ata-hard-drives what're you trying to do here? Focus on what you want to do, not how you want to do it

https://superuser.com/questions/740364/how-to-edit-this-resource-string-of-the-windows-dvd Not sure about if or how to fix this one

https://superuser.com/questions/629982/windows-magnifying-glass-window-turns-gray kinda hard to fix up. Its a valid question but 2 years down the road, and with no screenshot of what the issue is, its hard to answer.

https://superuser.com/questions/629134/alternative-software-to-dvdfab-application-to-rip-a-br-without-reconversion software recommendation so off topic.

https://superuser.com/questions/545709/disable-solid-colours-page-of-windows-wallpapers-menu comments are much too agressive :(. Might be a learning material recommendation, or could be fixed up.

**offered bounties**

[How to change Winamp's default Keyboard Shortcuts?](https://superuser.com/questions/280782/how-to-change-winamps-default-keyboard-shortcuts)

[How to set the color of the letters of the file-properties window, in windows 8/8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/727553/how-to-set-the-color-of-the-letters-of-the-file-properties-window-in-windows-8) (x2)

[Rename the user profile dir name in Windows 8 to the correct username, in a silent way?](https://superuser.com/questions/621233/rename-the-user-profile-dir-name-in-windows-8-to-the-correct-username-in-a-sile)

I don't see any deleted ones. (And you've given away almost twice the rep you've earned. Dude, keep some for yourself!). I'd also add losing privileges if you dip below a specific reputation level is part of the system, and no one, moderators or otherwise owe it to you to post comments on your behalf. We have an entire site to take care of, not just one user.

Comment: Thanks for provide a detailed answer and helped me to find (some?) of my deleted posts. I have a little questions. 1st: `some of your questions are roombaed` could you please clarify the meaning of this english word "roombaed"?. 2nd: I read a lot of other "guides" starting with the Help Center to know how to remove my ban, they always say **start by fixing your questions** but I don't understand this, in which way if I edit my questions it could contribute with this comunity if nobody will answer or nobody will note the existance of my questions?. I think that is for gain upvotes but.. IDK

Comment: I keep contributing hardly as I can by answering to other questions and upvoting good questions and answers until this year, but I still have this damn restriction...

Comment: Its SE slang. We have a automated thing that clears up unanswered/unupvoted questions periodically. We call it the roomba, and I use "roombaed" as shorthand for "It was deleted automatically by the roomba". A question edit would 1) make it clearer what the issue you want to solve is, making it more attractive to people looking at the site 2) with sufficient quality, encourage people to reopen it by improving quality 3) If it is a dupe, can be differentiated from the other question . My suggestions are things that you need to keep in mind if you get unbanned to avoid future issues too.

Comment: In addition, the restriction is *automated* We *cannot* (as in are unable to, not unwilling to) remove it manually. Also, that list covers *all* your deleted questions, and existing bounties, except the ones I undeleted for you.

Comment: ♦ yay! I can make newer questions!. I'm not sure if it was after I "fixed" one of my deleted questions or was because you in some way, but without your help probably Ill still banned in that way. I will keep in mind your suggestions for the future. Big thanks.

Comment: Try not to get anything deleted in future! There's only so much we can do

Comment: OMG... i'm too stupid. I confused **meta.superuser.com** with **superuser.com**, I noted it after I spent 20 mins writting a new questtion (I didn't posted it), I still banned from **superuser.com**. well, I will keep contributing wondering for the unban. thanks again!

Answer (score 5):

Oh no! You got question-banned... by the [system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans).

Your profile doesn't look like one moderators would love to suspend for and I don't quite see the fact a moderator can lift your ban in the near-time. For some reason, your ***questions*** were not so popular to the community and were deemed not good contributors nor helping the community by the system. So bam! You got yourself stuck in a question ban. What should you do? ***READ AND FOLLOW EVERYTHING THE LINK ON THE FIRST SENTENCE TELLS YOU TO DO TO LIFT THIS BAN.***

Moderators can not lift your ban. They can suspend your account and lift a suspension but not an asking-ban. If you have a big bunch of questions that were deleted quite early and were downvoted (a lot probably), that might contribute to your own ban. So get on Super User and start contributing more and stop ranting on Meta.SE when it is unnecessary.