# Too many edits issue. Post-ban support

Tags: support, questions, editing, moderation, asking-questions

### Scenario

I was banned the past year in 2014. I have a post-ban in which I can't ask any question in **[superuser.com](http://superuser.com)**.

Here are two discussions about my problem:

- [Am I a victim of any sort of StackExchange's banning system bug?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267783/am-i-a-victim-of-any-sort-of-stackexchanges-banning-system-bug)
- [Please allow me to ask questions again, after a year of being blocked](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/10810/please-allow-me-to-ask-questions-again-after-a-year-of-being-blocked)?

In the last url above which points to the main recent discussion, the gentle moderator provided me 12 links of my profile which points to questions I did, from those 12 questions 9 was deleted, from those 9 deleted questions I've edited/fixed 7 questions, and from those 7 questions recently 2 were approved to be undeleted.

---

### Problem

From the words above we could note the important detail: Yesterday I edited/fixed 7 deleted questions.

Yesterday I also edited/fixed some own non-deleted questions (I'm not sure if less than 5 questions)

Today I edited/fixed 5 own non-deleted questions, and this message appears when I tried to edit/fix one more question:

[image]

The message says "***Please contact a moderator If you require assistance***", well, that is what I'm trying to do with this post, if this is not the proper way to do this please indicate me how I should do.

I think that some of the **[superuser.com](http://superuser.com)** moderators has concern about how much I'm suffering this post-ban because after all my efforts I still banned by the system.

Note what the **[Helper Center](https://superuser.com/help/question-bans)** says:

[image]

...Sure?. Please see my activity of these recent days:

https://superuser.com/users/178741/elektrostudios?tab=reputation

My contributions are increasing day by day on which my positive votes gains x300 than my negative votes, but I see no unban from the system.

I feel like I'm doing this effort to contribute in a community on which I can't expect any beneffit, because I can't perform any question on **superuser.com**

---

### Question

I'm not sure which question to ask, the message on the image above lets me the opportunity to contact a moderator then I would like to ask if a modertaor could remove my lmit of 5 edits per day (or at least per today), if possible, because I would like to edit/fix all my questions because the post-ban.

If that is not possible, then please... just... I don't know what to ask exactlly... I will ask for any thing that a moderator could do to help me with this ban. Please, because I know that tomorrow I will edit/fix 5 own questions and I will still banned, and days will happen until I have edited/fixed all of my questions and I will still be banned with no reason because this wrong behavior which seems "broken" of the banning system of **StackExchange**.

Thanks for read.

Comment: Unfortunately, not many people really know how the automated bans system works, and the people who *do* know aren't sharing. <total guesswork follows> However, I suspect "positive contributions" is actually measured as rep level, and I vaguely recall this being mentioned in the past. Perhaps 500 and 1000 are thresholds that allow you more leniency.

Comment: Also, just a note: generally "corruption" is a *very* strong word to use, and in most contexts would imply that someone is being dishonest for their own gain. It seems that you are not a native speaker, and I suspect you're referring to the automated bans being "broken", but calling it "corrupt" sounds like you are throwing accusations at someone.

Comment: When you're question banned, it's usually a good choice to post high quality answers *in addition* to what you've already been doing (fixing your questions).

Comment: @Bob thanks for pointing that word, yes my native language is not English and for "corrupted" I will mean "broken" "wrong" "imperfect", I mean imperfections on its algorithms, I'll change that word. To be clear I don't think is anybody spying my profile and denying me the beneffit to ask a question, not that kind of corruption haha.

Comment: @Oliver Salzburg thanks for comment.After my post-ban I posted some answer (unregardless of how much answers was marked as accepted), but its very hard for me to help by writting answers in superuser.com because I have knowledge limitations on 90% of the questions, anyways I always try it when I have the opportunity. If StackExchange banning system "measures" the given answers then that is not good, they should think in the user knowledges to be comprehensive.There are a lot more of contributions that an user could do,but all those contributions seems that doesn't counts to unban.Unreasonable.

Comment: @ElektroStudios - I see you are spending considerable amount of time suggesting new tags to questions, but in nearly every case, you suggest no improvements to those questions.  Just keep in mind every suggested edit should attempt to improve or resolve any issues with the content.  Of course neither submitting answers to existing questions or proposing edits to existing content will reverse your current question ban.  The only way to do that is to improve your questions, so they are on topic high quality content, every other action I have seen you do isn't counting towards that happening.

Comment: "I will still be banned with no reason" - The reason you were question banned was legitimate, so there was a reason, you submitted more then enough low quality content to merit a question ban as evidence by it happening.  You were warned you were getting near the limit, you were given feedback on what you did submit in 2014, the first step to improving your future questions is to understand what was wrong with your existing content.

Comment: @Ramhound There was a good reason why I get banned. The thing is that NOW there is no reason to still banned after 1 year. I learned from my errors, be sure everybody!.

Comment: You made a comment that concerned me, when somebody says 'there isn't a reason for the ban", it tells me they don't understand what that reason was.  As been explained you have numerous questions that need improvement, when those questions have been improved and the community votes to indicate they agree, your automatic ban will be lifted.  *You have been told how to do that.  It might take a few days or weeks for the community to verify you have improved your content.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You keep hitting on the automatic limits we can't do anything about. No we *cannot* remove these limits and they are automatic and there's no way to undo them. The official line here is *you'll just have to do 5 edits a day* and make them good ones. I suspect the edit limit is to keep folk from vandalising their own posts.

Fact is, there's no hard and fast rule for lifting a question ban - we've given you the information you need, pointed out what can be fixed, and at the end of the day, you're going to be the one who tells *us* when the ban's lifted.

I *do* know someone managed to drag himself out of a question ban, but I can't tell you "You need 200 more reputation, 12 answers and a trained goat" to get out of your ban. I can tell you *you* can do it, and that more *good* answers, quality edits and other such works *would* help.

As for the algorithm, you need to consider that we've got several thousand users, and we have very few cases where we need to help folk overturn a ban. *It works*.

I was about to comment on the word choice, but that's done in the comments for me already.

As for the ability to answer. Consider this - I'm currently the number 6 user by reputation, and I post roughly 1 answer a day. Focus on the stuff you know, and *quality* and answering questions isn't that hard.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that deleted questions are counted several times in the formula to determine if a user is banned from asking questions.  So given the number of questions @ElektroStudios has submitted then have been removed or deleted  its entirely possible there isn't a way out of it.  As for my source for this information it was a comment by a SE employee I read many moons ago.